# Camera with transparency margin

Tags: android, camera

I need a camera function on my App. This is what I need:

[image]
(From barcode-scanner but I need something for making pictures)

I need a transparency margin. Now when I would press "shot photo" I need exactly this:

[image]

Someone know a tool like that?

Thanky in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to map that out yourself and crop the bitmap.

You can draw the boundaries of the transparency window on the Canvas of the FrameLayout your camera's view.

From there, you grab the position of the transparency window in relation to the screen and then use those boundaries to cut out the desired area from the bitmap returned by the camera.